# Giving Error message ' Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL ' while executing conf.js

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am getting the above error message when i am executing 1 spec file given below.i have set the all script timeout to 300000.

```
//Scenario 8: Verify Alert message when the user enter the unregistered email Id and other fields.
it('Verify Alert  message when New user registered itself for the first time',function() {
    FuncLib.ButtonClick('Close'); //Close the error message displayed in previous scenario
    Registration.Email.clear(); //Clear valid E-mail Id
    Registration.Password.clear(); //Clear Password
    Registration.ConfirmPassword.clear(); //Clear   Confirm Password 
    Registration.Firstname.clear(); //clear Firstname Password
    Registration.Lastname.clear(); //clear Lastname Password
    Registration.Phonenumber.clear(); //clear phonenumber
    browser.sleep(500);
    Registration.Email.sendKeys('Forfirmtestuser+user216@gmail.com'); //Enter valid E-mail Id
    Registration.Password.sendKeys('Hello1'); //Enter Password
    Registration.ConfirmPassword.sendKeys('Hello1'); //Enter wrong  Confirm Password 
    Registration.Firstname.sendKeys('candy'); //Enter Firstname Password
    Registration.Lastname.sendKeys('smith'); //Enter Lastname Password
    Registration.Phonenumber.sendKeys('9191919106'); //Enter phone number.
    expect(Registration.Checkbox.isPresent()).toBe(true); // Terms and condition checkbox should display
    Registration.Checkbox.click(); // select the Terms and condition checkbox
    Registration.Checkbox.click(); // select the Terms and condition checkbox
    browser.sleep(200);
        expect(Registration.RegisterButton.isPresent()).toBe(true);
        Registration.RegisterButton.click(); //click Register button
        browser.sleep(200);
            browser.driver.wait(function() {  // Wait for the current URL to change to Home page
                return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                    return (/home/).test(url);
                });
            });
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(Registration.HomeURL);
            console.log('When New user registered itself for the first time:');
                expect(Registration.AlertMsg.getText()).toEqual(Registration.msg6);
                Registration.AlertMsg.getText().then(function(text) {
                console.log(' When New user registered itself for the first time:');    //Jasmine expect statement : compare actual and expected value
                });
});
```

Comment: that formatting is not very helpful. you could try calling the jasmine done in the final then `function(done) { .... Registration.AlertMsg.getText().then(function(text) { done() `

Answer (score 2):

That is due to jasmine default time out. You can increase it in conf.js file using below code:

```
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
     showColors: true,
     includeStackTrace: true,
     defaultTimeoutInterval: 1440000//Increase the default jasmine time  
                                    //interval.
 },
```

Comment: Hello suresh, i have tried after setting the defaultTimeoutInterval: 1440000. But it does not work . If you have any other solution  than plz share it with me.